# Unable to use 'getByTestID' in testcafe

Tags: react-native, testing, automation, testcafe, testing-library

I am trying to use custom data-testID to identify elements. Below is my code -

```
    import { getByTestId } from '@testing-library/testcafe';
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
import { addTestcafeTestingLibrary } from 'testcafe-testing-library';
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';


export default async function disableVideo(browser) {
  await browser.click(getByTestId('Video-Button'));
}
```

I am calling disableVideo and seeing following error -

An error occurred in Selector code:

Error: Cannot call method 'getByTestId' of undefined

Am I missing something?? Below are my dependencies -

"dependencies": {
"@testing-library/testcafe": "^4.4.0",
"chrome-remote-interface": "^0.31.2",
"cross-fetch": "^3.1.5",
"testcafe": "^1.18.4",
"testcafe-testing-library": "^1.3.1"
}

Answer (score 1):

The `@testing-library/testcafe` package is not officially supported by TestCafe. Moreover, according to the error text, the issue is related to the `testing-library`, but not to `testcafe` itself.

Nevertheless, the TestCafe team will be able to help with solving this problem. Could you please share a simple reproducible example that uses only TestCafe?

Please note that TestCafe doesn't support [testing of ReactNative applications](https://testcafe.io/402636/faq#can-i-use-testcafe-to-test-react-native-apps).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error, and it was because I neglected to read the documentation.  You need to add this to your .testcaferc.json file:

```
"clientScripts": [
  { "module": "@testing-library/dom/dist/@testing-library/dom.umd.js" }
],
```